# React component not re rendering on window.location change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

So, I have a react component for a main menu.

Its a list of react-router `<Link/>` which point to different pages. Each link checks the `window.location.path` to figure out if it is the active page so that the active menu item can render differently.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";

class MainMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <Link to="/products" className={window.location.pathname === "/products" ? "active" : null }>Products</Link>
        <Link to="/sales" className={window.location.pathname === "/sales" ? "active" : null }>Sales</Link>
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

This was actually working fine, however I now want to connect this menu component to my redux store so that I can display some data from the store inside the menu, as soon as I add the `connect` function the menu breaks such that when changing pages the "active" class doesn't get applied. 
i.e. the component does not update even `though window.location.pathname` has changed.

I haven't included my store code because I've tested it with dummy reducers that do nothing and also I haven't even used the data anywhere in the component yet.

```
export default connect(state => ({ foo: state.bar }))(MainMenu);
```

I'm still not sure whether this issue is to do with connect or if connect has just highlighted a problem with using `window.location.pathname` and react doesn't know when to update.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink quote: "A special version of the <Link> that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL."

Answer (score 3):

React component won't rerender when you change window.location.pathname. Only state changes will cause component to rerender. You need to listen to window.pathname change and map it to state then only your component will rerender

For such things you can take a look at react-router. Add it your project and such things can be easily achieved.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I thought this might have been the case so I guess I'm wondering why it works without the connect function

Answer (score 0):

> The view changes when there's any change in this.state of the
>   component. I would suggest you to listen to changes in window.location

Here's the code

```
constructor(){
   this.state = {currentPath:window.location.pathname}

   window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      this.setState({currentPath:window.location.pathname})
   };
}
```

and in render()

```
render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <Link to="/products" className={this.state.currentPath === "/products" ? "active" : null }>Products</Link>
        <Link to="/sales" className={this.state.currentPath === "/sales" ? "active" : null }>Sales</Link>
      </List>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great solution. Not sure if the page 'unloads' because i'm using the browser router which doesn't actually reload the page

Comment: yes, but I saw in mozilla docs that, this particular event is triggered whenever windw.location.path changes. I don't know if it works. Can you please let me know if this works :)

Comment: While this might solve the OP's problem, it's an exercise in futility. As expected, React Router has a component called `<NavLink>` specifically designed to solve OP's actual problem.